# Android.test.TouchUtils methods don't work on headless emulator, help!

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I'm trying to get my Android tests running on headless emulator for future use on CI servers.
But non of the TouchUtils methods, like "*clickView()*" etc.. seem work this way.

I'm always getting SecurityException:

> "Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission".

Looks like it doesn't click the right objects in the first place. In normal GUI mode everything works fine.

Is there any way around this?
If no, which setup would you recommend to run all the tests on remote machines?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device is probably showing the lock screen. Check it with the *hierarchyviewer* or *screenshot2*.

You can unlock the screen by sending a menu button, for instance by using adb:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

(The keyevent code can be found in android.view.KeyEvent.)

Comment: Thank you, Robert! Works now just fine.